# Is it acceptable to use USB connectors in non-USB applications?

Tags: usb, sensor, connector

In my project I need fairly long (up to 5 meters) shielded cabling that has compact 4 pin connectors (will be used in a noisy environment). As I understand the shield of the cable should connect to the connector, which connects the shielding to the header, which is grounded on the PCB. I believe that a good choice here would be RJ45, but the size of the connectors is excessive.

From an electrical engineer's point of view, would it be acceptable to implement USB or microUSB ports for an application which has nothing to do with the actual USB protocol? Would this decision cause problems if it would become a commercial product? The cables are for connecting digital sensors to a controller.

Suggestions for alternatives to USB connectors are also welcome.

Comment: One day a customer came to me with this little story: He bought some heating regulation gadgets that go onto your radiator valve directly and control it. And they had usb connectors. So he wondered if instead of with the build in UI, he could connect his laptop somehow. He tried and the gadget was immedeately dead. What happened was that it directly took whatever came down the line and wrote it into its flash...

Comment: Try RJ18 - like RJ45 only smaller - often used for phone handset connections

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I get the message, it wouldn't be for home consumers, though.

Comment: @Icy - But there are no shielded RJ18 connectors, how do I manage cable shielding?

Comment: sorry missed that requirement, try Lemo connectors then.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing: often those are worse, because you know, "we know what we are doing"

Comment: @Icy - I like those very much, but the price almost induced a heart attack. I'd need quite a few of those and the price of the connectors alone will vastly outweigh the price of the rest of the device.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Heh, can't protect it against all of them I guess. I'd make sure nothing gets damaged if 5V is applied to the first USB pin.

Comment: Look at mini-DIN as a possible alternative. Cheaper than Lemo!

Comment: They're not much smaller than RJ45. And the experience with wobbly PS/2 connectors makes me doubt their reliability.

Comment: You might get away if you use connector and cable combinations which aren't allowed by the standard and not available on the market and get those specially made for you. But it's like a touchscreen, everyone tries to touch displays even if it's just a multimeter...

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing --  be careful about turning this into a shopping question.  "Is a USB connector good here?" is fine -- "what else should I use" is not.  Try chat

Comment: That said, go browse around the Molex site.

Comment: A natural question that occurs after finding out that what I have is not ideal is "what is?". I chose USB not because I have an affection to it, I absolutely hate it, but I simply found no other options. Molex was the first place to go, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your situation, and what the failure modes of plugging a USB cable into your device would be.  When people see a USB connector, people want to plug a USB cable into it.  A decade of user experiences confirms this behavior as valid.  If it makes no difference, and your device can laugh at 5V coming in on the USB pin, and you won't kill someone's laptop in the process, you should be OK, but your users might get confused.

Comment: It wouldn't be targeted at home users which might not resist the temptation to plug a mouse to it or try plugging it to a computer, but I'd make sure 5V wouldn't fry the sensor. Other than that, would this not be unprofessional for some reasons?

Comment: Don't get me wrong -  I'm not endorsing  the approach, which I don't care for very much.  It's begging for mistakes to happen, and doesn't show much regard for user experience.  When you can anticipate errors and confusion in design stages, and don't fix it, yes, that's unprofessional.

Comment: Alright. Do I have alternatives that do not double the price of the device?

Comment: If it's for consumer electronics, you should double the price of your device. On my workplace, we use USB connector for UART signals, but it is safe to plug it to USB (it has no effect), and it's only for internal use. As a matter of fact, it was designed to be restricted to internal use, but some customers use it for debug (on B2B market. The end user never see a single USB connector).

Comment: It is oriented more towards industrial use. Are you suggesting that it is normal for connectors to cost as much as the rest of the device?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing connectors being notoriously expensive is common, yes. In our products they often end up being the most expensive part (on it's own), so we try to reduce the number of them wherever possible.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that's not an option, each sensor must get it's own connector.

Comment: @RDrast, bad link

Comment: I apparently cannot post links in comments... Just google M8 Connectors.

Comment: I think the prob is the long link.  Molex has an M8 line.  http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=nanochange_40m841_products

Comment: Also a very pricy solution, I don't think I could pull that off. What about 2.5mm/3.5mm audio jacks? I've heard of people using these for data transfer and I think I've seen 4 conductor shielded cables for sale, is it also a poor choice? Would you be tempted to plug your headphones in it?